# Why complex types don't allow to reference entity types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, complextype

I do not understand why complex types do not allow to refrence entity types. I mean they do, but all properties of the refrenced entity type are then stored in the same table as the class including the complex types.

I do not see any reason for this and it is a great limitation.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

It seems Entity Framework cannot distinguish between the referenced entities. For example, it is unable to automatically assign keys to them:

[image: SQL Server Image]

The database in the previous image was created using the following code:

```
static void CreateAndSeedDatabase()
{
    Context context = new Context();
    ReferencedClass anotherClass1 = new ReferencedClass(){Name="instance1"};
    ReferencedClass anotherClass2 = new ReferencedClass() { Name = "instance2" };
    ComplexTypeClass complexType1 = new ComplexTypeClass(){ReferencedClassProp = anotherClass1};
    ComplexTypeClass complexType2 = new ComplexTypeClass() { ReferencedClassProp = anotherClass2 };
    Parent parent1 = new Parent() { ComplexTypeClassProp = complexType1 };
    Parent parent2 = new Parent() { ComplexTypeClassProp = complexType2 };
    context.Parents.Add(parent1);
    context.Parents.Add(parent2);
    context.SaveChanges();
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<Context>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Context>());
        Database.Initialize(true);
    }

    public DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }

}

public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ComplexTypeClass ComplexTypeClassProp { get; set; }
}

[ComplexType]
public class ComplexTypeClass
{
    public ReferencedClass ReferencedClassProp { get; set; }
}

public class ReferencedClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```